# Dynamically pass the SQL parameter in Go

Tags: sql-server, go

I have the below Go program, which works fine for dynamically passing only one parameter. In my requirement, I will not know the parameter name and parameter value in advance. I may need to pass 1...n parameter to the query and values as dynamic manner. How can I achieve the same?

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // Open a connection to the database
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(host:port)/database")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Prepare the SQL statement with placeholders for the parameters
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn = ?")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer stmt.Close()

    // Execute the SQL statement with the parameter values
    rows, err := stmt.Query("myvalue")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    // Iterate over the result set
    for rows.Next() {
        var id int
        var name string
        err := rows.Scan(&id, &name)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(id, name)
    }
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? The obvious solution would be to use [`fmt.Sprintf`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Sprintf) and/or [`strings.Builder`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Builder) to construct your query and [explode](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) a slice of values when you call `Query`.

Comment: @Adrian Do **NOT** use sprintf or similar string manipulation to substitute values into SQL!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I know, which is why I specifically did not suggest doing that.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be using [Squirrel](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel).
You can add conditional queries like in the example given in their readME.md.

> if len(q) > 0 {
> users = users.Where("name LIKE ?", fmt.Sprint("%", q, "%"))
> }

Answer (score 1):

I know very little about Go (I'm here because I *do* know SQL Server), but I can find [the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Stmt.Query), and see this:

> Query executes a prepared query statement with the given arguments

The use of the plural "arguments", instead of "argument", plus my experience using the `?` placeholder in other environments, tells me you can pass multiple arguments to `Query()` and they will be interpreted as positional parameters:

```
stmt.Query("myvalue1", "myvalue2",.... "myvaluen")
```

Where `myvalue1` matches to the first prepared `?` placeholder in the SQL command string, `myvalue2` matches to the second, and so on.

I think you know this, but for completeness I need to add: do **NOT** use string manipulation to include these values in the SQL command.